# Failed to open stream, directory correct

Tags: php

[image]

```
require(file(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config/config.php'));
```

**structure:**

[image]

the require is coming from :

[image]

whats going on here? I already tried different directories and it still gives me this error.

Comment: The `file` function **reads the contents** of a file. Why are you using it? Try, `require(__DIR__ . '/config/config.php'));` instead.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/73tr47 :|

Comment: tried it and it still doesn't work, more errors instead...
even if I put the config content on my login.php it still gives me the same error.

Comment: login.php is in `auth/config` but the error message says it's searching in `auth`